# C# Selenium contains() not finding the correct element

Tags: c#, selenium

For some reason the I keep getting the wrong file returned to me. I keep getting a file with the name FC6...

I ran through the debugger and the search variable stays FC5 the whole time, I am guessing it has something to do with the contains() function, but I haven't had an issue anywhere else.

Looking for a way around this issue, thanks in advance.

```
        public override void selectFiles()
        {
            foreach (string key in searchKeys)
            {
                IWebElement keyElement = base.getKeyElement("FC5");

                //get the parent of the key element
                IWebElement parentElement = keyElement.FindElement(By.XPath("./parent::*"));

                //get the download tag in the parent element
                IWebElement element = parentElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Download')]"));

                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

                actions.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();
            }
        }

        public IWebElement getKeyElement(string searchKeys)
        {
            IWebElement element = null;

                string keyString = "//*[";
                string[] keyList = searchKeys.Split(",");
                bool firstKey = true;
                foreach (string searchKey in keyList)
                {
                    if (firstKey)
                    {
                        keyString = String.Join("", new string[] { keyString, "contains(text(), '", searchKey, "')" });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        keyString = String.Join("", new string[] { keyString, " and contains(text(), '", searchKey, "')" });
                    }

                    firstKey = false;
                }
                keyString = String.Join("", new string[] { keyString, "]" });

                element = waitForVisibility(By.XPath(keyString));

            return element;
        }

        public IWebElement waitForVisibility(By element)
        {
            try
            {
                return new WebDriverWait(driver,        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and yours is bad. You catch and swallow all excetpion, wich is a cardinal sin of exception handling. I have two articles on the thematic that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Understandable, but can you help with the question?

Comment: If you got code like that, chances are you swallowed the exception giving you the information you need. Your whole code is also confusing: `searchKeys` is clearly indicated to be a collection. Yet `getKeyElement(string searchKeys)` get's a single string? `selectFiles()` is not even used anywhere in this code. Either it does not mater or you did not show us how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, first time to know `OpenQA.Selenium` after copy-paste your code to my visual studio.

First of all, here is definition of `WebDriverWait.Until`:

```
public TResult Until<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> condition){}
```

I wonder if your `ElementIsVisible` a fuction, but can you change it to Lambda expression?

```
public IWebElement waitForVisibility(By element)
{
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Until(x=>SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element)); //the lambda depends on your context.
}
```

Here are some suggestions to your code:

```
public override void selectFiles()
{
    //should you run base.selectFiles() before or after the loop? base.selectFiles() has no any logic?

    foreach (string key in searchKeys)// key is never used inside loop, serious?
    {
        IWebElement keyElement = base.getKeyElement("FC5");
        //getKeyElement support multiple keys, why do you always get FC5 in each loop? 
        //should you move above line out if no need to getkey again

        IWebElement parentElement = keyElement.FindElement(By.XPath("./parent::*"));
        IWebElement element = parentElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Download')]"));//is this `Download` the `key`?

        //where is this driver from? why not move this line out of loop
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

        actions.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();
    }
}

// I simplified this code
public IWebElement getKeyElement(string searchKeys)
{
    var keys = string.Join(" and ", searchKeys.Split(",").Select(searchKey => $"contains(text(),'{searchKey}')"));

    //check keys in debug mode
    return waitForVisibility(By.XPath($"//*[{keys}]"));
}

public IWebElement waitForVisibility(By element)
{
    //I guess the issue is in Until. it is a Func<> but you may give it a result.
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    .Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Nope. Really just remove the try/catch entirely. Catching Exception is a stupid idea that will bite you all around your body. Never do that.